# recursively rename the files with folder name

Tags: shell, awk

Im trying to rename the files in the folder recursively using

```
find . -iname "*bw" -exec rename /accepted_hits.bw .bw '{}' \;
```

I want to change the file name  in each folder with the respective folder name

for eg. test1/accepted_hits.bw to test1.bw

Comment: Could you give an example? If you have ./a/accepted_hits.bw, is the expected result ./a/a?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Lety, i have files ./a/accepted_hits.bw, ./b/accepted_hits.bw . now want to change it to ./a.bw and ./b.bw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this command:

```
find . -iname "accepted_hits.bw" | while read file; do dir=$(basename $(dirname $file)); mv $file ${dir}.bw; done
```

where:

- `find` command search recursively file whose name is "accepted_hits.bw"
- `-i` option means case insensitive
- symbol `|` means that the output of `find` command is the input for `while` command
- `while read file` loop on each line and execute commands between `do` and `done`

`find` command will output:

```
./a/accepted_hits.bw
./b/accepted_hits.bw
```

so block of command will execute two times. `dirname $file` on the first line gets `./a` and `dir=$(basename $(dirname $file))` is the name of directory, in this example `a`.

`mv` command move file `accepted_hits.bw` in `.` directory and rename it as `${dir}.bw`

Use `man` command to view manual page of each command.